# How to send a string to a server using PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, cordova

How do I send a string to a server using PhoneGap? I know that PhoneGap has FileTransfer to upload a file to a server using a POST request. But if I just have a string that I would like to send rather than a file how would I do that? I'd still like to use a POST request so that I can send the string to the server and then have the server send a response back.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The web-service calling is vary according format of message server want. Your question isn't yet constructive. Anyway see this http://kmithi.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/8/ may be it will help you.

Comment: XmlHttpRequest is the way to go.

Comment: So, I've got a XmlHttpRequest that I'm doing with an AJAX call. Here is my JS code http://pastebin.com/Ps9vznWH. I have a button that calls this function when it is pressed. My new problem is that the message being sent back when the ajax call is done is always the same when it should have changed. How can I fix this?